# How do I cache an Eigen solver as a class member?

Tags: c++, templates, eigen, eigen3

**I have some geometric data whose vertices I move by solving some costly linear system. I want to re-use that system between function calls so I'm trying to encapsulate it as a class member in a class which I can give to the geometry framework I'm working with, but I don't know how to name the solver's type.**

---

I obtain the solver like this:

```
#include "./eigen3/Eigen/Sparse"
#include "./eigen3/Eigen/SparseCore"
#include "./eigen3/Eigen/SparseCholesky"

Eigen::SimplicialLDLT<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>> sparseSolver(mySPDMatrix);
```

so my first idea was to write a class like this (some members omitted):

```
class MatrixCachePerObjectData : public PerObjectData    /* 'PerObjectData' is required by the framework */
{
public:
    Eigen::SimplicialLDLT<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>> cached_solver;
    MatrixCachePerObjectData(Eigen::SimplicialLDLT<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>> cs) : cached_solver(cs) {}
};
```

which wouldn't compile. I have since realized that this is because I named an (abbreviated) constructor and not a full type, so I looked into the documentation and changed the member's type to:

```
Eigen::SimplicialLDLT<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>, Eigen::Lower, Eigen::AMDOrdering<int>> cached_solver;
```

This does compile, but only if I comment out the (updated) constructor. If I leave the constructor in I get an error telling me I'm attempting a "use of deleted function" and that it is "implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed". I thought what is happening is that an implicit copy must be happening which includes a call to the constructor, so I added an '&' to it:

```
MatrixCachePerObjectData(Eigen::SimplicialLDLT<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>, Eigen::Lower, Eigen::AMDOrdering<int>>& cs, Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> cm, bool cv) : cached_solver(cs), Q_T(cm), cache_valid(true) {}
```

but this gives me the same error, and I'm not quite sure why. My best (but still bad) guess wold be that instead of calling a `copy`-function is it calling an equivalent `move`-function, but truth be told I'm really clueless here. So I gave up on the constructor and tried to access the member directly:

```
auto mpc = new MatrixCachePerObjectData();
mpc->cached_solver = sparseSolver;
```

This predictably failed again with the same error. I tried printing out the type to see if I made an error there and got:

```
N5Eigen14SimplicialLDLTINS_12SparseMatrixIdLi0EiEELi1ENS_11AMDOrderingIiEEEE   // typeid(sparseSolver).name()
```

which just confuses me more. Any help is appreciated.

**What is the correct way to cache an Eigen3 solver as a class member?**

Comment: Eigen's solvers are not copyable, so you can either wrap it in a `std::shared_ptr` or let `MatrixCachePerObjectData` creates/owns the solver and get a reference to it when needed (instead of creating a solver and then copying it to the cache).

Comment: Hm, those 2 approaches still give me "use of deleted function". Which makes sense since both explicitly require me to explicitly write out the full type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working self-contained example following the second approach I suggested above:

```
#include <Eigen/Sparse>
using namespace Eigen;

class Cache {
    typedef SimplicialLDLT<SparseMatrix<double> > Solver;
    Solver m_solver;
  public:
    Solver& solver() { return m_solver; }
};

int main()
{
  Cache cache;
  auto& solver = cache.solver();
  SparseMatrix<double> A = MatrixXd::Random(10,10).sparseView();
  A = A.transpose() * A;
  solver.compute(A);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this example. My problem was trying to put the solver into the class rather than using the one apparently already existing in the class via `compute`.